# Integration of trigonometric equation with negative power

Tags: integration

We have to evaluate the following integration:
$$
\int(\sin x)^{-11/3}(\cos x)^{-1/3}\,dx
$$

For this I tried.

And I'm uncertain if we can use Wallis’ theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint write it as $\frac {\sec^4 (x)}{(\tan (x))^{11/3}} $  put $\tan(x)=t $ but $sec^2 (x)dx=dt $ then integral reduces to $\frac {1+t^2}{t^{11/3}} $ .Now split the terms and its easily integrable.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=$$
$(\sin(x))^{\frac{ -11  }{  3 }}(1-(\sin(x))^2)^{\frac{-2}{3}}\cos(x) dx$

put $\sin(x)=t$. then the integral becomes
$$I=-\int t^{\frac{-11}{3}}(1-t^2)^{\frac{-2}{3}} dt$$

now put $u=t^{\frac{-8}{3}}$ and you can finish.

Answer (score 1):

Divide numerator and denominator by cos^x  to convert the given function in terms of sec^2x  and tanx
Then substitute tanx=t and proceed

Comment: This would be easier to read if you had used MathJax to format it. There's no clear numerator/denominator in the question, making it harder to know what you mean, and you've answered a question that is a little over a month old and has an accepted answer(which says something similar to yours). That is three reasons this is not really a worthwhile addition to the site, or a good use of your time.